# Prompt user with yes/no textbox during SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

What ways are there to create textboxes during an SQL query? I have a query that searches for duplicate rows in my database. I'd like to inform the user of any duplicates and prompt them with a textbox that says something like "250 duplicate entries have been found. Would you like to delete them? Yes/No" If yes, the data is deleted. If no, nothing happens.

Comment: You'll need something that can handle that kind of interactivity, perhaps you could build something in Visual Studio with a front end that can handle your original call and then push the corresponding DELETE query upon selection.

Comment: What client are the users going to be running to initiate the query?

Comment: You want an *application*, which lives on the computer the user is using.  The SQL database is a server, which may be very far away from the user and have no permissions to talk to the user.  This is a pretty simple application, but still an application.

Comment: Ouch, downvoted for something I genuinely didn't know... I'll try building something to trigger a DELETE query then. What should be my starting point for looking up an application to program this with?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't do this with just SQL.  You'd have to use something else to build an interface that can prompt the user for input.  Javascript, PHP, C#, or a shell scripting language would all work for this.